# Display Friends list in multiple Views

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am currently working on project that requires a friends list, right now, I have code that displays the list when the home controller is run:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var friendslist = new FriendsList();
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userid = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
            var model = _friend.FriendsList
                .OrderBy(f => f.RequesteeID)
                .Where(f => f.RequesterID == userid).ToList()
                .Select(f => new FriendsList
                {
                    UserName = f.UserName
                });

            return View(model);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And the view's code is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-navbar dropdown-menu">
<li class="nav-header">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    Friends List
</li>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <span class="pull-left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

As you can imagine, this works fine when navigating to the home controller, but when I navigate away, I get an error letting me know that the action is not handled. My question is, is there a way to reuse the code from the home controller without pasting it into every other controller that needs it. I appreciate any help I get with this.

Mike

Comment: You want to reuse the code in `HomeController`? Why don't you make a wrapper for it?

Comment: You could create a Partial View and add a @functions block in the view to contain your C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `PartialView` of it, then call (render) this `PartialView` in each target `View` of different `Controllers` easily.

Call the `PartialView` inside another `View` of different `Controller`:

```
 @Html.PartialView("~/views/Home/friends.cshtml", FriendModel);
```

Or call it without passing `Model`:

```
 @Html.PartialView("~/views/Home/friends.cshtml");
```

Or use:

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/views/Home/friends.cshtml", FriendModel);
```

Create `PartialView`:

[image]

To create a `PartialView` you can search it in google there are many result or read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC).

Comment: Thank you very much RAM for your help.

Comment: Good luck Micheal... ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Html.RenderAction in your view for your purpose

```
@Html.RenderAction("FriendsList","Home");
```

first parameter is action name and second is controller name